# How to get to Tweet in native iOS Twitter app from another app's webview?

Tags: twitter

Often I'm in some iOS app (e.g. Facebook) and there's a link to some Tweet's URL. When I tap on it, it takes me to the web version of the Tweet inside a webview in whatever app I was in. Then if I want to like the Tweet, I have to login to Twitter again inside the webview even though I'm already logged in to Twitter in the native iOS Twitter app. Is there a quick way to get to the same Tweet in the native app?

Answer (score 1):

At least in the case of Facebook I found an easy way to do this, from the top right menu:
[image: Facebook webview menu]

Answer (score 0):

You answered it yourself. Facebook has a link to open in twitter. So I'm not sure how handy my answer woulld be for all the different social media apps.

For the situation where the app only gives you a link, there's a great ios app called [**Opener**](https://itunes.apple.com/app/opener-open-links-in-apps/id989565871) (~$2).

Link to [their website](http://www.opener.link/), where you can find [a list of the supported apps](http://www.opener.link/apps.html).

<sup><sub>Most of the time I use this for going back and forth between Youtube app and ProTube. ProTube is my main youtube app (because of picture in picture and background play), but for what ever reason it won't work with apple tv like 99% of the time. So sometimes when I've already started watching the video in ProTube and want to use apple tv, I end up using opener to open the video in Google's Youtube app which works fine with apple tv (for the most part).</sub></sup>

[image]